# How to insert one div into another div in Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

Code for parent-div dialog:

```
                $("#parent-div").dialog({
                    title: 'Parent',
                    width: parseInt(100, 100),
                    height: parseInt(190, 10),
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: "Cancel",
                                    click: function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Save",
                                    click: function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                });
```

Code for child-div dialog:

```
<div id="child-div"></div>
```

How to insert child div into parent div in Jquery Dialog along with buttons save and cancel which are already added ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#parent-div").append($("#child-div"));
```

or if you want child-div to be the first element

```
$("#parent-div").prepend($("#child-div"));
```

You could string this together with your dialog call like so:

```
$("#parent-div").dialog({
    // your options
}).append($("#child-div"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
$('#child-div').appendTo('#parent-div');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) in javascript.

```
var childDiv = document.getElementById("child-div");
document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(childDiv);
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/mPpvw/)